# Azure Global VNet peering and WebApps

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps

I am using Global VNet peering in Azure (2 networks in 2 different regions) and I'd like to access a VM I have in one of them from a WebApp I'd like to integrate with the other.

I have tried integrating the WebApp through a gateway and also directly without a gateway (the preview function) and I managed to see VMs from the same VNet but I am unable to access the VM from the globally peered VNet by its private IP.

Is this possible to achieve and if so, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible since you could use **remote gateways** or **allow gateway transit** in globally peered virtual networks **in preview**, currently. The preview is available in all Azure regions, China cloud regions, and Government cloud regions. Read more [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#requirements-and-constraints). Moreover,

> Route tables and global peering are not yet available with the new
>   VNet Integration.

So you could try to use the existing VNet integration with a VNet which has a P2S VPN gateway. To configure peering to work with your app, you could refer to [peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#peering) configuration.

1. Add a peering connection on the VNet your app connects to. When adding the peering connection, enable `Allow virtual network access` and check `Allow forwarded traffic` and `Allow gateway transit`.
2. Add a peering connection on the VNet that is being peered to the VNet you are connected to. When adding the peering connection on the destination VNet, enable `Allow virtual network access` and check `Allow forwarded traffic` and `Allow remote gateways`.
3. Go to the App Service plan > Networking > VNet Integration UI in the portal. Select the VNet your app connects to. Under the routing section, *add the address range of the VNet that is peered with the VNet your app is connected to*.

Please **note that** you must add the peered VNet address in step 3. Then sync network, you will see the address range in the **IP ADDRESSES ROUTED TO VNet**. In my case, my peered VNet address range is 10.0.0.0/24.

[image]

The tools `ping`, `nslookup` and `tracert` won’t work through the console due to security constraints. Navigate to the web app console, we can use `tcpping` to verify the TCP connection with its private IP address. Please check if vm does not allow incoming pings or that the network security group for the virtual machine blocks them. See more troubleshooting details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#troubleshooting).

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are truly a godsend, this works! Thank you so much! Just a note for anyone who would want to try this - as is written in the peering docs you provided, the setup for the global peering with gateway transit and remote gateways can't be done through the UI. It's pretty easy through the console, however.

Comment: Thanks, Maybe it's a mistake in the doc or something else not update yet, I can see and set them via the UI when I peer each other with two VNets.

Comment: I just noticed one more thing, you can't have multiple networks globally peered with remote gateways enabled - sadly, there is only 1 possible, so if I need to connect more than 2 regions, I have to duplicate a lot of my infrastructure.

Comment: Yes, One peered VNets only have one gateway.  So you may consider creating a [hub-spoke-hub-spoke topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/shared-services#overcoming-vnet-peering-limits). I have not validated if this true.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. I would appreciate if you can elaborate further on the steps required to create and configure gateways. I am always getting Gateway status N/A regardless of what I try. Is there a restriction for both VNETs to be on the same subscription or can different subscriptions be used?